# SSO using Azure AD

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

If the user is logged in to an APP which is associated with one Azure AD 1. 
How can we make sure that the user is automatically logged in to another APP which is associated with Azure AD 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope `multi-tenant` concept helps you. Not sure.

Comment: If both apps allow you to be logged in via AAD 1 or AAD 2 and you are logged into only that tenant, then you get SSO. We need to know a lot more about the scenario to offer specific assistance.

Comment: I have application 1 that uses Azure AD B2B. User is logged in to the application 1. If the user is redirected from application 1 to application 2, I want the user to be automatically logged in to the application 2 as well. Application 2 is using the AZure B2C AD.

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding , you have two apps :

app1 is protected by Azure AD and app2 is protected by Azure AD B2C. If you want to do so , you should create a custom identity provider(based on OpenID Connect , you should map your Azure AD stuff here) in your Azure AD B2C tenant and apply it on your signin policy.

With this process done , once your user logged in app1, if the user be redirected to app2 , this user will see a B2C login page firstly , and if he click the custom identity provider(Azure AD) , Azure AD B2C will recognize the user and log user in directly , no entering password action needed .

This doc has detailed steps to map it : https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-azure-ad-b2c-to-azure-ad-via-the-b2c-custom-identity-provider-42fbc2832e32